# Changing background color onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dont know if it is possible to do but i this is my code.

```
function start(blauw){  
    document.getElementById(blauw).style.background="white";
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id= niks></td>
        <td id= niks></td>
        <td id= blauw onclick="start(id)">1</td>
        <td id= blauw onclick="start(id)">2</td>
        <td id= blauw>3</td>
        <td id= blauw>4</td>
        <td id= blauw>5</td>
        <td id= blauw>6</td>
        <td id= blauw>7</td>
        <td id= blauw>8</td>
        <td id= niks></td>
        <td id= niks></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i want to achieve that if i click on it the background will turn into white so people now what they are booking. but do i have to give everything an own ID? because right now if i click on "2" only "1" turns white and "2" won't turn white.

(excuse me for my bad english)

Comment: `id` attributes in HTML must be unique. If you want to apply the same ID to multiple elements, use `class` instead, and target it using `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing attributes just pass the element itselfe:

```js
        function start(element) {
            element.style.background = "green";
        }
```

```html
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td class=niks></td>
            <td class=niks></td>
            <td class=blauw onclick="start(this)">1</td>
            <td class=blauw onclick="start(this)">2</td>
            <td class=blauw>3</td>
            <td class=blauw>4</td>
            <td class=blauw>5</td>
            <td class=blauw>6</td>
            <td class=blauw>7</td>
            <td class=blauw>8</td>
            <td class=niks></td>
            <td class=niks></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And as mentioned in the comments - ID`s  had to be unique!!

EDIT:

Altered function to switch the background color.

```
    function start(element) {
        var backgroundColor = element.style.background;
        if (backgroundColor === "green") {
            element.style.background = "red";
        } else {
            element.style.background = "green";
        }
    }
```

So this is a very simple demo

See [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rhajyxjh/)

Comment: can i do that backwards too? That if the color is white i can turn it into the original color?

Comment: Of course you can! I will make a little sample. But what about jQuery? Can you use jQuery??

Comment: Never used jQuery. This is a project for my school and i just started a month ago :)

Comment: I made an update... If this was helpfull dont forget to vote it as the right one! @CeesvandenToren

Comment: is it can use color hex code?